In DuckDB, Is it possible to change a value based on the previous value ordered by another column without using UDFs?
I have a column A which I want to increment or decrement according to columns B and C.
The logic is this:

if lag(A) = 0 and if B = 1 then A=1
if lag(A) = 1 and if C = 1 then A=0
the lag(A) is from ordering by D

I can't figure out how to implement this logic in DuckDB. I think the issue is that A depends on the previous value.
select
  unnest(array_agg(row(B, C) order by D)) as list1
from
  my_table

I figured I must be something to the un-nested version of list1 and I thought list_reduce might help I can't figure out how. Another thought is that recursive CTEs might help. But I was not able to find a solution.
Perhaps it's not possible in DuckDB and I need to use a list UDF.
If it's possible in any other variant of SQL then I would love to hear the answer too.
Example data
   B C A  D
1  0 0 0  1
2  1 0 1  2
3  0 0 1  3
4  1 0 1  4
5  0 1 0  5
6  1 0 1  6
7  1 0 1  7
8  0 1 0  8
9  0 0 0  9
10 0 1 0 10

R code to generate data
fn = function(b, c) {
  l = length(b)
  A = vector(mode="integer", l)
  A[1] = 0
  for (i in 2:l) {
    A[i]= A[i-1]
    if((b[i] == 1) & (A[i-1] == 0)) {
      A[i] = 1
    } else if ((c[i] == 1) & (A[i-1] == 1)) {
      A[i] = 0
    }
  }
  A
}


d = data.frame(
  B = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  C = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1)
) %>% dplyr::mutate(
  A = fn(B, C)
) %>% 
  mutate(D = row_number())

d


Could you please provide some sample data and the expected result?

added Thanks @JonasMetzler

A [mcve] is supposed to include both sample table data and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

When you write lag(A), do you mean lag(A) in the original table, or in the updated table?  Dealing with the former case would be easy, so it's reasonable to assume you mean the latter, but it would be helpful if (a) you were explicit; and (b) your sample data were sufficiently informative so that the distinction was clear from the expected results.

In general sql is not the greatest tool to run such iterative calculations, but you can do it with recursive cte:
with recursive cte as (
    select b, c, d, 0 as a
    from df
    where d = 1

    union all

    select
        d.b, d.c, d.d,
        case
            when c.a = 0 and d.b = 1 then 1
            when c.a = 1 and d.c = 1 then 0
            else c.a
        end as a
    from df as d
        inner join cte as c on
            c.d = d.d - 1
)
select *
from cte

┌───────┬───────┬───────┬───────┐
│   b   │   c   │   d   │   a   │
│ int64 │ int64 │ int64 │ int32 │
├───────┼───────┼───────┼───────┤
│     0 │     0 │     1 │     0 │
│     1 │     0 │     2 │     1 │
│     0 │     0 │     3 │     1 │
│     1 │     0 │     4 │     1 │
│     0 │     1 │     5 │     0 │
│     1 │     0 │     6 │     1 │
│     1 │     0 │     7 │     1 │
│     0 │     1 │     8 │     0 │
│     0 │     0 │     9 │     0 │
│     0 │     1 │    10 │     0 │
├───────┴───────┴───────┴───────┤
│ 10 rows             4 columns │
└───────────────────────────────┘


Thanks for the answer. So I have trouble understanding how does the recursive cte know to terminate? or "terminate" not the right way to think about it? If I have multiple groups each with these structure, would this solution still work? I only presented the logic for one account.

expression "terminates" when there's no rows returned from 'recursive' part. It will work for sets indeed, but you might need to adjust join / initial selection
